# SQL syntax: outer table_name

Tags: sql

I have a project with this query that I don't get something in it.

```
Select 
    c.prop_table1,
    (SELECT max(t.taux_table_x) FROM DB3:table_x t  
     WHERE month(t.date_prop_x) = month(c.prop_of_x) 
     AND year(t.date_prop_x) = year(c.prop_of_x)
    )*1 table_x, 
    ''||date(c.prop_of_x) Alias
FROM DB1:table_name1 d, DB1:table_name2 c, outer DB2:table_name a 
WHERE 
    c.value_i  = d.value_i AND 
    c.property =d.property  AND 
    (c.num_table_name2 =a.no_dos_adh OR c.ref_cred=a.no_dos_adh) AND 
     c.abcd not in ('P','S')
```

I don't know what `outer` is expressing exactly. Is it a left/right or full join? Or is it something else?
**thanks for the help everyone**

Comment: Which database program? Doesn't look like valid syntax to me.

Comment: it looks like a table name aliased as table3.

Comment: that's the thing it's a weird query it was made in 2008 or 2007 & i don't know what it even means it's actually from db:table, db:table2, outer  db2:table  i know that vs2005 was used for thus

Comment: @Blorgbeard It's most likely code written for Informix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks a lot like your query is written using the (IBM) Informix SQL dialect. If that is the case then the `outer` should be a left outer join as it has a table on its left side (I believe a right join would be `from outer tab1, tab2`)

The syntax predates the SQL-92 standard but should still be valid (?) with Informix.

Rewritten as standard SQL it would probably look like this:

```
SELECT 
    c.prop_table1,
    (
     SELECT max(t.taux_table_x) FROM DB3:table_x t 
     WHERE month(t.date_prop_x) = month(c.prop_of_x) 
       AND year(t.date_prop_x) = year(c.prop_of_x)
    )*1 table_x, 
    '' || date(c.prop_of_x) Alias
FROM 
    DB1:table_name1 d
INNER JOIN 
    DB1:table_name2 c ON c.value_i  = d.value_i AND c.property = d.property
LEFT JOIN 
    DB2:table_name a ON (c.num_table_name2 = a.no_dos_adh OR c.ref_cred = a.no_dos_adh) 
WHERE 
    c.abcd not in ('P','S')
```

Comment: do you have an idea about how this can converted to Linq it's kind of my big issue with the multi databases & tables

Comment: @TheNewGuy Sorry, but I don't know LINQ that well. I've update the answer with how the SQL should look, that's the best I can do. You could maybe take that query and post a new question on how to convert to LINQ (but you should include some effort of your own first).

Comment: i will find something & i learned with Linqer & some internet help in  2+ days  thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what outer is expressing exactly is it a left/ right or full join?

Not withstanding syntax problems with your sql code, outer is the set union of left and right. In your example, this is the equivalent

```
(table1,table2) union (table3)
```

But your SQL is sorely incomplete to give any more specific answers.

Comment: oh & any idea how to express that in linq ? i know how to that between queries not inside the query

Comment: How to what? Can you be more specific? Post the actual query or complete your question in complete sentences.

Comment: Do you have an idea about how to change the `(table1,table2) union (table3)` into a Linq query i know that if you have 2 queries you can use .union but how can i do that inside the query so i have the supposed union on table3

Comment: Where is the currently working SQL now? If you provide that I can show to convert it to Linq. What you provided is not valid SQL.

Comment: That looks like pre-92 SQL standard, which means I don't know how to Linq handles it. Perhaps you should repost this question with a linq tag first. Your original question was unrelated to this follow-up question.